# Wordpress doesn't display accents after migration

Tags: mysql, encoding

**I know this is a common question**, but I've searched a lot and only experience this since a few months, without knowing what's causing this issue of course, maybe since a Wordpress update.

This is now happening each time I move a WP installation to another server. My procedure :

- Export DB from dev site.
- Search & Replace old URL by new URL.
- Import DB in new site.

**Before answering me I messed with the encoding sets**, please consider this :

- In my fresh new DB, special chars are well displayed (french - see acccents) :

[image: PHPMyAdmin]

- In front-end, accents fail :

[image]

- In WP Dashboard, page titles don't even display, although they're displayed in the menu (cf. previous pic) ('pas de titre' means 'no title')

[image]

What should I do to migrate WP installation properly ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Alleluia...**

After multiple trials (like converting my tables to utf8_unicode_ci -- didnt work), here's the only successful fix I found :

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
```

In `wp-config.php`, replace `utf8mb4` by `utf8`.